# Unpacking and the ESP trick

Tags: gdb, unpacking

I recently heard about the esp trick: some packers push all registers on the stack, and when unpacking is done, they are restored. Placing a hardware breakpoint on esp we can stop there and get the original entry point.

Why is it necessary to use a hardware breakpoint? [This site](http://yangseo.tistory.com/52) argues that because software breakpoints modify the code. But why is that a problem here?

Every example I met uses Ollydbg. How can I set such a breakpoint in gdb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Placing a hardware breakpoint on esp we can stop there and get the
>   original entry point.
>
> Why is it necessary to use a hardware breakpoint?

The value of `ESP` is an address on the stack. The data at that memory address may get read or written, but won't get executed¹ since it's not code. Software breakpoints are only useful on code that gets executed, and since the data at that memory address won't get executed, a software breakpoint won't be helpful.

*¹ There are exceptions to this, but it's out of context for your question.*

> How can I set such a breakpoint in gdb?

In gdb, you can set a hardware breakpoint on the memory address pointed to by `ESP` by setting a **watchpoint**, which is documented [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html).